# What's going wrong with my list.append?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to solve a classic river crossing puzzle and I'm kind of stuck on this. Basically I have a function `getmoves` which gives me a list containing lists of valid game states. The function calculates valid game states by going through all possible moves and appending valid ones to the output.

Problem is every time I append to `output` the whole `output` changes.

```
def getmoves(gamestate):
    """
    Returns a list of all possible moves
    """
    boatshore=None
    moveablemen=[]
    moveableobjects=[]
    output = []
    gs = gamestate

    for item in gs:
        if item['name'] == 'boat':
            boatshore = item['shore']

    for item in gs:
        if (item['shore'] == boatshore and item['name'].find('man')!=-1):
            moveablemen.append(item)

    for item in gs:
        if (item['shore'] == boatshore and item['name'] != 'boat'):
            moveableobjects.append(item)

    for man in moveablemen:
        for obj in moveableobjects:
            if (man != obj and man['value']>=obj['value']):
                possiblemove = move(man['name'], obj['name'],gs)

                if shorenetworth(possiblemove) == True:
                    output.append(possiblemove)
                    pp.pprint(output)

    return output
```

Output is this after one append operation:

```
[   [   {   'name': 'manA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'manB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'manC', 'shore': 1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'coinA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'coinB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'coinC', 'shore': 1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'boat', 'shore': -1}]]
```

Output is this finally:

```
[   [   {   'name': 'manA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'manB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'manC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'coinA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'coinB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'coinC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'boat', 'shore': -1}],
    [   {   'name': 'manA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'manB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'manC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'coinA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'coinB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'coinC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'boat', 'shore': -1}],
    [   {   'name': 'manA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'manB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'manC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'coinA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'coinB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'coinC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'boat', 'shore': -1}],
    [   {   'name': 'manA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'manB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'manC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'coinA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'coinB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'coinC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'boat', 'shore': -1}],
    [   {   'name': 'manA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'manB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'manC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'coinA', 'shore': -1, 'value': 3},
        {   'name': 'coinB', 'shore': 1, 'value': 5},
        {   'name': 'coinC', 'shore': -1, 'value': 8},
        {   'name': 'boat', 'shore': -1}]]
```

I'm sure I probably made a stupid mistake somewhere but I have no idea where so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
def move(man, name, gsinput):
    """
    move two items
    """
    for item in gsinput:
        if (item['name'] == name or item['name'] == man or item['name'] == 'boat'):
            item['shore'] *= -1
    return gsinput
```

This is the function which value is appended to `output`.

Comment: given two `name`s and the gamestate, multiplies the value of `shore` for the dictionaries containing the names by `-1`.

Comment: Best add the code for that function to the your question. It is the return value of that function that is appended, after all.

Comment: if it helps, the only function which references `output` in my program is `getmoves(gamestate)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I got the problem. I was appending the variable `possiblemove` to my list instead of a string so when the variable changed the output changed as well.